# How do I change the location where addons are saved? Windows Blender 4.0+

Tags: add-on

The standard place to save addons is from `C:\%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\`

Inside Preferences, I go to *Preferences > File > Script Directories* and change to `F:\My Blender all files\scripts\addons\`

After that, I have fun going to install my new 5 GB addons and nothing changes.

They continue to be installed on the C drive

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't replace the default scripts installation directory, you can only set an additional one, and switch to it when installing a script.

#### Setting up a script directory

Open the preferences with the menu Edit > Preferences.

Under the File Paths category, Script Directories, you can add a custom directory and give it a name:

[image]

From there, you can move your scripts installed in the default folder to your custom folder under a `addons` subfolder. If you restart Blender, it will pick up any scripts installed there.

#### Installing an addon

You can install addons two ways: manually move files to your custom directory, or using Blender's GUI under Preferences > Add-ons category > Install button.

While browsing for the new addon to install, you can set the Target Path to your custom script directory:

[image]

It will always use Blender's default directory, so you have to do that change every time.

Comment: For this answer, people will come here again and again